# Django 3.0.7 unable to change STATIC_ROOT path

Tags: python, django

Hi I am new to django,

I have created a django project with following urls.py and settings.py codes respectively

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('',include("user_mgmt.urls")),
 path('',include("dashboard.urls")),
 ]  

if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"spaat_static")
```

then I am collecting the static files using:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

but Django is collecting files in the *../staticfiles* directory, whereas I have defined *../spaat_static* in STATIC_ROOT.

[image]

How to solve this issue ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I figured it out, django-heroku was interfering with settings.
It is working fine after commenting this link: django_heroku.settings(locals())

Answer (score 0):

THIS LINE :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"spaat_static")
```

Try to change it to :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"spaat_static")
```

And tell me how it goes !
Peace.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add this :)

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"spaat_static"),
]
```